# MySQL - How to combine INSERT, INSERT IGNORE and ON DUPLICATE UPDATE into one working query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Case 1:

```
ID                Loc                In                    Out
----------------------------------------------------------------
null              null               null                  null
```

Working query for this case:

```
INSERT INTO Inventory VALUES( 'PA', 'Area 1', now(), NULL );
```

Case 2:

```
ID                 Loc                In                    Out
----------------------------------------------------------------
PA                 Area 1             2017-11-16 11:20:09   null
```

Working query for this case:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Inventory VALUES( 'PA', 'Area 1', now(), NULL );
```

Case 3:

```
ID                 Loc                In                    Out
----------------------------------------------------------------
PA                 Area 1             null                  2017-11-16 11:20:09
```

Working query for this case:

```
INSERT INTO Inventory VALUES( 'PA', 'Area 1', now(), NULL )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE In = now(), Out = NULL;
```

How can I combine the above 3 "Working query" into one?

Basically, the goal is to only execute case 3 if `PK == Duplicate` and `In == NULL`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`INSERT IGNORE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) and [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) are mutually exclusive. They both handle the situation when the row to be inserted conflicts with an already existing row on an `UNIQUE INDEX`.

`IGNORE` converts the errors into warnings and this basically lets the query succeed and ignore the new values.

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` updates some of the fields of the existing row with the new values.

Both clauses are used only if an `UNIQUE INDEX` conflict happens; they are ignored otherwise. This makes both of them work in your case #1

> Basically, the goal is to only execute case 3 if `PK == Duplicate` and `In == NULL`.

A carefully crafted `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause can do the job:

```
INSERT INTO Inventory VALUES('PA', 'Area 1', NOW(), NULL)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `In` = IF(ISNULL(`In`), VALUES(`In`), `In`),
    `Out` = NULL
```

The value of expression `` IF(ISNULL(`In`), VALUES(`In`), `In`) `` is `` VALUES(`In`) `` (the value of `In` in the `VALUES()` list to be inserted) if  the current value of column `In` is `NULL` or the current value of column `In` if it is not `NULL`.

This way, the value of column `In` is replaced by the value provided by the `INSERT` query only if its current value is `NULL`.